# Previous sprites staying when changing y_positions to move

Tags: pygame

I'm making a game where the player controls a sprite that catches falling food.

However, I'm having trouble with the falling food part.

```
import pygame
import random
import time

d_w = 800
d_h = 600
fall_speed = 5

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((d_w, d_h))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

BGCOLOR = (0, 155, 0)

goodFood = pygame.image.load('burg.png')

def randFoodGen():
    x_food = d_w/2
    y_food = 0
    return x_food,y_food

def BurgGen():
    x_food, y_food = randFoodGen()
    screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
    while True:
        y_food = y_food + fall_speed
        if y_food > d_w:
            x_food = (random.randrange(0, d_w))
            y_food = -30
        screen.blit(goodFood, [x_food, y_food])
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)

BurgGen()
```

It ends up keeping the previous position of the falling food sprite, like this:
[Anger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36DBm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `screen.fill(BGCOLOR)` needs to be within the `while` loop.

```
def BurgGen():
    x_food, y_food = randFoodGen()
    while True:
        screen.fill(BGCOLOR)
        y_food = y_food + fall_speed
        if y_food > d_w:
            x_food = (random.randrange(0, d_w))
            y_food = -30
        screen.blit(goodFood, [x_food, y_food])
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)
```

That will at least solve the persisting burger problem. The reason is that before you draw a new burger, you have to wipe the screen of the burger you drew previously.

Also, if you are going to have multiple falling objects, you might want to make a [pygame.Rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) to represent each falling object. You might also want to make a python list of those pygame.Rect objects.

```
falling_objects = []  # create empty list
```

Whenever you need to create a new falling object, create a pygame.Rect and .append it to the list.

```
new_object = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
falling_objects.append(new_object)
```

Then, to update the objects positions, you loop through the list and update the Rects

```
for obj_rect in falling_objects:
    obj_rect.move_ip(0, fall_speed)
```

Use a similar for-loop to blit the image at each location

```
for obj_rect in falling_objects:
    screen.blit(food_image, obj_rect.top_left)
```

A bit in-depth but I hope that helps a bit.